# What is special about operator-> and how does it work?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, operators

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
};

class B
{
    A a;

public:

    B(int a, int b, int c, int d) : a{ a, b, c, d } {}

    A* operator->()
    {
        return &a;
    }

    A* operator++(int)
    {
        return &a;
    }

    A* pointer()
    {
        return &a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b(1, 2, 3, 4);

    //std::cout << b->->a << ' ' << b->->b << ' ' << b->->c << ' ' << b->->d << std::endl;

    std::cout << b->a << ' ' << b->b << ' ' << b->c << ' ' << b->d << std::endl;

//  std::cout << b.pointer()a << ' ' << b.pointer()b << ' ' 
//              << b.pointer()c << ' ' << b.pointer()d << std::endl; 

    std::cout << b.pointer()->a << ' ' << b.pointer()->b << ' ' 
                << b.pointer()->c << ' ' << b.pointer()->d << std::endl; 

    //std::cout << b++a << ' ' << b++b << ' ' << b++c << ' ' << b++d << std::endl;

    std::cout << b++->a << ' ' << b++->b << ' ' << b++->c << ' ' << b++->d << std::endl;
}
```

Here in this code the `operator->` and the function `pointer` returns exactly the same thing. But when when I call the `operator->` I can treat `b` as if it was the actual pointer. Whereas if I call the function `pointer` I have to use the arrow operator to access the members of `a`. That applies to `operator++` also. Is this a unique behavior only for `operator->`? How does `operator->` work?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's special for overloaded [`operator->`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators#Built-in_member_access_operators).

(emphasis mine)

> If a user-defined operator-> is provided, the operator-> is called again on the value that it returns, recursively, until an operator-> is reached that returns a plain pointer. After that, **built-in semantics are applied to that pointer**.

That means the member access like `->a` is applied on the returned pointer `A*` at last.

Answer (score 1):

> How does operator-> work?

For a pointer, `ptr->member` is shorthand for `(*ptr).member`.

If operator-> overload for class returns a pointer to an object, then `class_object->member` is equivalent to `pointer_returned_by_the_operator->member` which is equivalent to `(*pointer_returned_by_the_operator).member` as per the equivalence in the previous paragraph.

Besides a pointer, the operator-> overload for class can return another class object that overloads operator->. In such case, operator-> is applied recursively until an overload returns a pointer, in which case the previous paragraph applies.

The overloads for the unary operator* and operator-> are separate, but as long as operator-> returns pointer to same object as operator* returns a reference to, then the same behavioural equivalence remains between `class_object->member` and `(*class_object).member` - although they would invoke separate operator overloads.

In your particular case, `b->c` is equivalent to `b.a->c` (where `b.a` is accessed in member function), because the overloaded operator returns a pointer to `this->a`.

> Is this a unique behavior only for operator->?

Yes.

Comment: I think the description by songyuanyao is better; it covers the recursion. That's easily fixed though. Replace `(*pointer_returned_by_the_operator).member` by `(class_object.operator->())->member`. That is the actual code equivalent.

Comment: @MSalters I've updated the answer to cover the case of returning a non-pointer.